# Making an animated underscore in java

Tags: java

Its not really an animation, but I want it so i have a flashing underscore next to my text. I want this to simulate that more text can be entered..

e.g. one second its '_' and the other second its gone..

Thanks :D

*ps* I tried an idea where i had a while(flashing) loop and in there i made a string equal '_' and then made it equal '' but that didnt work..

```
while(flashing) {
    s = "_";
    s = "";
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT:::

This is how i am displaying the string in the game:

```
drawCenteredString(fontRenderer, "Missile Command Center" + s, width / 2, 40, 0xffffff);
```

Comment: How are you displaying the string? What interface are you using?

Comment: Its for a simple minecraft mod I'm making

Comment: You're not conveying the value of the variable to any interface though.  Not even System.out.

Comment: drawCenteredString(fontRenderer, "Missile Command Center" + s, width / 2, 40, 0xffffff);

Comment: You'll need to add a sleep between setting `s` to an underscore and removing the underscore in order to actually emulate flashing.

Comment: How would i do that? Using threads?

Comment: You can use `Thread.sleep(int millis)` to delay the current thread's execution.

Comment: @Vulcan  `Thread.sleep(int)` is not something that you should call on the EDT for anything that uses the EDT (e.g. Swing & AWT).  A Swing based `Timer` can take care of it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I assumed the code in question was already in another thread, true though.

Comment: I agree, not to actually using sleep, but I also agree that for a newbie it's easier to understand this kind of animation starting from the sleep method.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Vulcan said, you actually can't do this with a while loop. You have to 'redraw' the centeredString every second or so, once with an underscore and next time without the underscore

Comment: I kind of got the part, but how exactly would I 'redraw' it?

Comment: how is the rest of the screen 'redrawn' every 10ms or whatever the delay is?

Comment: Every tick, I think its 10ms yeah

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what kind of graphic libraries you are using.

If you want to do something like a flashing underscore there are two ways, one can be very bad, the second can be better.

The first one is something just like (pseudocoded):

```
while(flashing){
    textView.setText(textView.getText()+"_"); // I am assuming that you are using a text view, take this as pseudocode, you can do to whatever you want.
    sleep(500); //that is half a second
    textView.setText(textView.getText().substr(0,textView.getText().length()-1));
    sleep(500);
}
```

The second is better.
I assume you are using something like OpenGL to draw the graphics (as minecraft do, if I remember well).

private long timePassed = 0;
public void draw(long delta){
    timePassed += delta;

```
String t = textView.getText();
if(timepassed > blinkingSpeed){
    timepassed = 0;
    if("_".equals(t.substr(t.length()-1,t.length()))){
        //The last char is the underscore, i remove it.
        textView.setText(t.substr(0,t.length()-1));
    }else{
        //The last char isn't an underscore. I add it.
        textView.setText(t + "_");
    }
}
```

delta is a difference between the last time we done a loop and the actual time.
so when calling draw method you should have something like this

```
//metod where draw is called

delta = Sys.getTimer() - lastTimerGotten;
lastTimerGotten = Sys.getTimer();
draw(delta);

//etc etc
```

Obviously each frame rendering you should call the draw(long delta) method.

I hope you understand what I am trying to explain you.
There is no way to make what you first wrote work.

Comment: I modified it a bit, and it says that if("_".equals(t.substring(t.length()-1,t.length()))) is a null pointer

Comment: I edited my post, see what "delta" is intended. Also just not copy-paste my code, because I paid attention to the pseudocode, not the code itself.

Comment: also, you will have to check all vars name and, of course, you need to take the string value from the correct place. I supposed it was something like a TextBox, but you have to check the correct method to get the text and set a new text.

Comment: Do you have skype? Itll be easier to discuss, or some other place to discuss this properly, add me on skype if you do: madcrazydrumma

Comment: I encourage you to use this site, if you really need a discussion there is a chat (top of the page) also there are many posts in SO that are related to animation and similar. I can't understand what isn't clear in my answer ;)